# How to convert \u0421 into letter "C"?

Tags: json, perl, utf-8, encode

I made a post query to server and got json. It contains wrong symbol: instead "Correct" I got "\u0421orrect". How can I encode this text?

A parse_json function performs it like "РЎorrect";

I found out that

```
$a = "\x{0421}orrect";
$a= encode("utf-8",  $a);
```

returns "РЎorrect", and

```
$a = "\x{0421}orrect";
$a= encode("cp1251",  $a);
```

returns "Correct"

So I've decided to change \u to \x and then to use cp1251.

```
\u to \x
```

I wrote:

```
Encode::Escape::enmode 'unicode-escape', 'perl';
Encode::Escape::demode 'unicode-escape', 'python';       
$content= encode 'unicode-escape', decode 'unicode-escape', $content;
```

and got \x{0421}orrect.

And then I tried:

```
$content = encode( 'cp1251', $content );
```

And... nothing changed! I still have \x{0421}orrect...

I notice something interesting:

```
$a = "\x{0421}orrect";
$a= encode("cp1251",  $a);
```

returns "Correct"

BUT

```
$a = '\x{0421}orrect';
$a= encode("cp1251",  $a);
```

still returns "\x{0421}orrect".

Maybe this is a key, but I don't know what I can do with this.

I've already tried to encode and decode, Encode:: from_to,JSON::XS and utf8.

Comment: [Unicode Character 'CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES' (U+0421)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0421/index.htm)

Comment: "got json": What is the Content-Type response header value?

Comment: @mob I have seen this page, but it didn't help me to make my code work)

Comment: @TomBlodget `'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: It seems you are confusing yourself with your debugging output. The original response processing works or could work as in the answer by @ikegami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention escaping multiple times, but you want to do the opposite (unescape).

`decode_json`/`from_json` will correctly return "Сorrect" (Where the "C" is CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES).

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $json_utf8 = '{"value":"\u0421orrect"}';
my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);
```

---

You do need to encode your outputs, though. For example, if you have Cyrillic-based Windows system, and you wanted to create a native file, you could use

```
open(my $fh, '>:encoding(cp1251)', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

say $fh $data->{value};
```

If you want to hardcode the encoding, or if you're interested in the encoding output to STDOUT and STDERR as well, check out [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231890).

Comment: _decode_json/from_json will correctly return "Сorrect"_ nope, I still get РЎorrect

Comment: I performed `use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );`

`my $json_utf8 = '{"value":"\u0421orrect"}';`
`my $data = decode_json($json_utf8);`
`open(my $fh, '>:encoding(cp1251)', "test.txt")`
`or die("Can't create \"test.txt\": $!\n");`
`print $fh $data->{'value'};`
`say $data->{'value'};` and got РЎorrect and, surprisingly, emty text file....

Comment: It will print the wrong thing to STDOUT because you didn't encode what you send to STDOUT. This is covered by my answer already. It didn't create an empty file as you claim, however. It correctly writes `Сorrect` encoded using cp1251 to the file.

Comment: Well, if you got the error `Can't call method "say" on unblessed reference`, it's because you didn't add `use feature qw( say );`. And of course, you should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`, though that shouldn't have an effect here.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I got Correct into file, I don't know what it was and whay I didn't see this word. And I encodid STDUT using `use PerlIO::encoding;` but got \x{0421}orrect... Any way Correct in file - it is a big progress) Howewer,  I am writing API, so I should process this json and return it in correct form... How can I made this word become `Correct` into my code?

Comment: `use PerlIO::encoding;` doesn't do anything. You'd need `use open ':std', ':encoding(...)';`. Again, this is covered (by a link) in my answer.

Comment: Of course, I used not only `use PerlIO::encoding;`. I tried to encode stdout by using `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` but it brought me an error, so I wrote `{
   local $PerlIO::encoding::fallback = Encode::PERLQQ();
   binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(cp1252)";}` It didn't make my code work (I still got \x{0421} orrect). But it didn't give me any errors too, what made me think that I am on the right way and problem still not in encoding stdout) Finally I used exactly what you wrote `use open ':std', ':encoding(cp1251)';` and... it works, I get this magical "Correct" on my console! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if you realise this already - I just think it's worth pointing out so we're all on the same page.

- Character number `\x{0421}` has the description ["CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER ES"](https://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+0421) and looks like this: С
- Character number `\x{0043}` has the description ["LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C"](https://www.mclean.net.nz/ucf/?c=U+0043) and looks like this: C

So depending on the font you're using, it's entirely likely that the two characters appear identical.

You asked "How can I encode this text?" but you didn't explain what you mean by that or why you want to "encode" it.  There is no encoding that will convert 'С' (\x{0421}) into 'C' (\x{0043}) - they are two different characters from two different alphabets.

So the question is, what are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to check if the string returned from the server matched `"Correct"`?  If so, that simply won't work, because the server is returning the string `"Сorrect"`.  They might look the same, but they are two different strings.

It's possible that whole situation is an error in the server code and it should be returning `"Correct"`.  If that is the case and you can't rely on the server reliably returning the `"Correct"`, one workaround would be to use a [character replacement](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0//perlop.html#tr%2f_SEARCHLIST_%2f_REPLACEMENTLIST_%2fcdsr), to "normalise" the string before you inspect its contents.  For example:

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );

my $response = <<EOF;
{
    "status": "\u0421orrect"
}
EOF

my $data = decode_json($response);

my $status = $data->{status};
$status =~ tr/\x{0421}/C/;

if($status eq "Correct") {
    say "The status is correct";
}
else {
    say "The status is not correct";
}
```

This code will work now, and in the future if the server code is fixed to return `"Correct"`.